# materializecss navigation dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

I try to use materializecss dropdown menu feature but out of four dropdown menu items, I am only seeing two of the items in the dropdown menu. Here is my HTML code

```html
<nav class="white blue-text">
  <div class="navbar-wrapper container">
    <!-- <a class="brand-logo center waves-effect waves-light" href="javascript:void(0)">Abdul-Samii</a> -->
    <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-menu" class="button-collapse indigo-text"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
    <a href="#" class="brand-logo left">
      <img src="images/logo.png" class="top-logo">
    </a>

    <ul class="hide-on-med-and-down right">
      <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="about.html">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown1" href="javascript:void(0)">Gallery</a>
      </li>
      <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
        <li><a href="#!">Videos</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#!">Publication</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#!">Interviews</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#!">Pictures</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="javascript:void(0)">News</a>
      </li>
      <li class="waves-effect waves-light active"><a href="events.html">Events</a>
      </li>
      <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="partners.html">Partners</a>
      </li>
      <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-menu">
      <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="about.html">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Gallery</a>
      </li>
      <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="javascript:void(0)">News</a>
      </li>
      <li class="waves-effect waves-light active"><a href="events.html">Events</a>
      </li>
      <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="partners.html">Partners</a>
      </li>
      <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

and the only thing I did to my nav in my css is this:

```css
nav ul a {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: #2196F3;
}
nav,
nav .nav-wrapper i,
nav a.button-collapse,
nav a.button-collapse i {
  height: 105px;
  line-height: 105px;
}
```

check the navigation bar on this link: http://www.jalasem.com
and click on gallery to understand what i am saying

Comment: Please create a demo of your issue with all resources linked. This will help you get an answer very soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess what i got what u wanted..
There was a very small thing which made your code break..
I just removed the **class="waves-effect waves-light"** from the`<li>` tag of dropdown.

Below is Working code and its all CDN files so just copy and paste my code to any file, save with .html extension and run directly.

**Header part**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
<head><title>
    </title>

    <!-- Font-Awesome CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"></link>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/css/materialize.min.css">


</head>
```

**Next is the Body with nav**

```
<body>

    <nav class="white blue-text">
      <div class="navbar-wrapper container">
        <!-- <a class="brand-logo center waves-effect waves-light" href="javascript:void(0)">Abdul-Samii</a> -->
        <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-menu" class="button-collapse indigo-text"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        <a href="#" class="brand-logo left">
          <img src="images/logo.png" class="top-logo">
      </a>

      <ul class="hide-on-med-and-down right">
          <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="about.html">About Us</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown1" href="javascript:void(0)">Gallery</a>
          </li>
          <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
            <li>
                <a href="#!">Videos</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#!">Publication</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#!">Interviews</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#!">Pictures</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="javascript:void(0)">News</a>
        </li>
        <li class="waves-effect waves-light active"><a href="events.html">Events</a>
        </li>
        <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="partners.html">Partners</a>
        </li>
        <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-menu">
      <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="about.html">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Gallery</a>
      </li>
      <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="javascript:void(0)">News</a>
      </li>
      <li class="waves-effect waves-light active"><a href="events.html">Events</a>
      </li>
      <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="partners.html">Partners</a>
      </li>
      <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
```

**Finally the script and style with body end tag and footer**

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

**style for nav are same as u used i have not added in the code but you add it and then run the code**

Hope u got my ans.
good luck..